# Recursive calculus of sine not working

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm learning Haskell and I have been practising doing some functions by myself, in this functions are included the calculus of sine using recursion, but I get strange results.

The formula I'm using to calculate the sine is this one:

[image: Maclaurin series]

And my code is this:

```
--Returns n to power p
pow :: Float->Integer->Float
pow n p = 
   if p == 0 then 
      1
   else
      if p == 1 then
         n
      else
         n * (pow n (p-1))

--Finds a number's factorial
f :: Integer->Integer
f n =
   if n == 1 then
      n
   else 
      n * (f (n-1))

--TODO: Trigonometric functions ( :v I'll do diz 2)
sinus :: Float->Char->Float
sinus n deg = 
   if(deg == 'd')then
      sinusr 0 (normalize (torad n)) 0 
   else
      sinusr 0 (normalize n) 0 

--Get the value equivalent to radians of the presented degrees
torad :: Float->Float
torad v = ( (v * pi) / 180 )

--Recursive to get the value of the entering radians
sinusr :: Integer->Float->Float->Float
sinusr k x result = 
  if k == 130 then
   result + ( ((pow (-1) k ) * ((pow x ((2*k)+1))) / (fromIntegral (f ((2*k)+1)))))
  else
   result + (sinusr (k+1) x ( ((pow (-1) k ) * ((pow x ((2*k)+1))) / (fromIntegral (f ((2*k)+1))))))

--Subtracts pi/2 the necessary times to get a value minor or equals to pi/2 :v
normalize :: Float->Float
normalize a = a - (fromIntegral (truncate (a / (pi*2)))*(pi*2))
```

For example, the output it's this:

```
*Main> sinus 1 'd'
1.7452406e-2
*Main> sinus 1 's'
0.84147096
*Main> sinus 2 's'
NaN
*Main> sinus 2 'd'
3.4899496e-2
```

Can someone tell me why it is showing me that?
I have worked the same logic with Lisp, and it runs perfectly, I just had to figure out the Haskell syntax, but as you can see, it is not working as it must be.
Beforehand, thank you very much.

Comment: Always include the _expected_ output if the output isn't what you expect. Also, if possible, localize the problem. Aaaaaand don't use `Float`.

Comment: Speaking of output: the MacLaurin series formula is okay, but please paste the output of your program as text, and not as an image.

Comment: By the way, if you're able to fix your problem, I __strongly__ suggest you to have your code reviewed at [CodeReview.SE] later on (as soon as it works).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single point arithmetic isn't accurate enough for to calculate a trigonometric function. The exponent doesn't have enough bits for the large, intermediate numbers in `sinusr`. Or, to be blunt, the following number doesn't fit a `Float`:

```
ghci> 2 ^ 130 :: Float
Infinity
```

As soon as you hit the boundaries of floating point numbers (`-Infinity`, `Infinity`) you usually end up with either those or `NaN`.

Use `Double` instead. Your implementation of lisp *probably* uses double point precision floating point numbers too. Even better, don't recalculate the whole fraction in every step, instead update the nominator and denominator, then your values won't get too large for `Float`.

Comment: "Even better, don't recalculate the whole fraction in every step, instead update the nominator and denominator, then your values won't get too large for" -- In support of this point, it is worth noting that not even `Double` is enough for the factorial of 261 (as in `fromIntegral (f (2*130+1))`). While that doesn't lead to an immediately visible error, it does make all terms with `k` larger than 16 zero, given that dividing by `Infinity` results in zero.

Comment: @duplode funny enough, this exact formula was the one we had to implement in our C programming crash course. And since C doesn't have arbitrary large integral numbers, we had to come up with that "trick" ourselves. Ah… Good times.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
I just changed from Float to Double, now it's working perfectly.